# iPhone app widget for advertising on website

Tags: iphone, ios, ads

Does apple offer any app widgets or resources for creating an advertisement for your iphone app on your own website? Or are you on your own for creating an image/text for advertising your app on your website? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They offer [Marketing Resources](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html). There are some graphics which you can use and alter to your own specific needs for your app. E.g. placing some screens in their devices etc..